# Estilos para commandButton

Tags: java, html, css, jsf

Tengo un problema al poner estilos a un `h:commandbutton:`

-Mi **css** al que hago referencia no lo puedo modificar.

-Mi `commandbutton` tiene como input `type="submit"` y hereda los estilos de las cajas de texto (input).

-El estilo para mi botón están para las etiquetas `button`

-Al crear las etiquetas `style` al verlo en el navegador están comentadas.

Mi botón tiene el mismo tipo de letra que las cajas de texto y un ancho determinado, no esta trayendo los estilos que estan hecho para los botones.

> PD: Sorry por el formato estoy desde el celular.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar poner el css del command button para modificar el estilo por defecto , codigo a modo de ejemplo :

```
.ui-widget .ui-button { /* aqui */ }
```